# How to save workbook and clear userform with a CommandButton?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to save my excel workbook and clear my userform inputs with a reset button.

I've tried a few different things like `ThisWorkbook.Save` and  `UserForm1.Show` but its not working right.  The code posted looks like it saves and reloads the userform, but then it closes. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Unload Me
    UserForm1.Show
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

I would like the user to input data into the form then click the reset button so that it saves and clears the form to be used agian.

[image]

Comment: Might be worth giving [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) a read for more detail on why not to `Unload Me` or `UserForm1.Show`.

Comment: Do something like this for each control - `txtDimension = ""`

Comment: @BigBen I have read that article, it helped me on another part of this project, but it is well above my current skillset though. I've been trying to apply it to my reset button, but no luck.:(

Comment: @braX That worked! Thank you